# Como retirar caractere de uma String e transformar em valor inteiro com PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso converter uma string em inteiro e retirando o "R$ " do valor.

```
$valor = $_SESSION['valor'];

echo $valor;
```

Me retorna a string: R$ 25,00

Preciso que retire o R$ e me retorne o valor em inteiro: 2500.

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se não estiver ligando para decimais, virgulas e quiser extrair somente números do texto, faça o seguinte:

```
$str = $_SESSION['valor'];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);

echo $matches;
```

A saída será `2500`.

Comment: Obrigado @CypherPotato e David Alves. Deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode simplesmente retirar a vírgula e o R$, dessa forma:

```
$sua_variavel = str_replace ( ',' , '' , $variave_inicial );
$sua_variavel = str_replace ( 'R$' , '' , $sua_variavel );
```

Na primeira linha vai retirar a , e na segunda o R$

Answer (score 0):

Varias formas de se chegar a esse resultado, outra delas é:

```
$valor = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/i","",$valor);
```

Porem é uma saída numérica, para converter para `int`, usa-se:

```
$valor = (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/i","",$valor);
//ou
$valor = intval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/i","",$valor));
```